# How to transfer a few databases from MariaDB master to another master

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, migration, mysqldump

I must transfer databases (everything without system's databases) from one replication server to another replication server.
Everything is on MariaDB (10.0.20) and i need to do it with minimal downtime.
On source servers I have master (serverA1), slave (serverA2), slave (serverA3) replication.
On destination server I have the same situation - master (ServerB1), slave (ServerB2), slave (ServerB3).
Now I must move databases from servers A to servers B, with minimal downtime and not to ruin replication.
Server A and B have different databases.
In future Server A, will be offlined.

Comment: *Server A and B have different databases.*  What does that mean?  You're trying to move the databases from A onto B, while B is already a working system?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Server A is already working system and B also, I will soon turn off the server A. And now all the databases with A I have to move to B, where it already working another system.

Comment: Are you actively writing to A1?  And you need to copy the data, then catchup on what is missed during the copy?

Comment: @RickJames - Yes

Comment: Check out Percona's Xtrabackup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that you can do is this: ServerB must become a slave to ServerA

Let's assume the following

- ServerA1 has an IP of 10.20.30.40
- ServerA1 has databases db1, db2, db3
- ServerB1 has databases db4, db5, db6
- ServerA2 is a Slave of ServerA1
- ServerA3 is a Slave of ServerA1
- ServerB2 is a Slave of ServerB1
- ServerB3 is a Slave of ServerB1

Here are the Steps

## STEP 01

Make sure ServerA and ServerB and their slave has unique server_id values

## STEP 02

#### OPTION #1 : Dump from ServerA1

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=password
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE schema_name NOT IN "
SQL="${SQL} ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql','test','sys')"
DBLIST=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL} 2>/dev/null"`
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--single-transaction --routines --triggers --master-data=2"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} -B ${DBLIST} | gzip > DataFromServerA.sql.gz
```

#### OPTION #2 : Dump From a Slave of ServerA1

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=password
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE schema_name NOT IN "
SQL="${SQL} ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql','test','sys')"
DBLIST=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL} 2>/dev/null"`
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--single-transaction --routines --triggers --dump-slave=2"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} -B ${DBLIST} | gzip > DataFromServerA.sql.gz
```

Note: In option #2, you use [--dump-slave](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_dump-slave). This tells a slave to publish its master's binary log file/pos to the output of mysqldump instead of its own.

## STEP 03 : Get the Replication Log File and Log Position

```
less DataFromServerA.sql.gz | head -23 | tail -2
```

This will echo the `CHANGE MASTER TO` with the log file and position of the Master

For the sake of this example, say the output is

```
-- CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='bin-log.001236', MASTER_LOG_POS=102938;
```

## STEP 04 : Transfer Dump into ServerB1

## STEP 05 : Load Dump into ServerB1

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=password
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
gzip -d < DataFromServerA.sql.gz | mysql ${MYSQL_CONN}
```

## STEP 06 : Create Replication User for the Cutover

On ServerA1, run

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE,REPLICATION CLIENT
ON *.* TO 'cutover'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'cutover';
```

## STEP 07

On ServerB1, run

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
master_host='10.20.30.40',
master_port=3306,
master_user='cutover',
master_password='cutover',
master_log_file='bin-log.001236',
master_log_pos=102938;
START SLAVE;
SLAVE SLAVE STATUS\G
```

NOTE: Please make sure there are no firewall issues

## STEP 08 : Wait for Replication to Catch up

Keep running on ServerB1 `SLAVE SLAVE STATUS\G` until `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0

## STEP 09 : Stop your writes to ServerA1

After disabling all apps that write to ServerA1, run this on ServerA

```
SET GLOBAL read_only = 1;
FLUSH TABLES;
FLUSH LOGS;
```

## STEP 10 : Point all the apps at ServerB1

## STEP 11 : Disable MySQL Replication from ServerA1

On ServerB1, run

```
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE ALL;
```

## STEP 12 : Decommission ServerA1, ServerA2, ServerA3

***CAVEAT : Please try all this out on Staging Servers Before Doing So on Production***

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Thx Rolando everything works fine. DO you know other mechanism that works faster than mysqldump. when database size is bigger then 10 GB.

Comment: I read about innobackupex, but i don't know how restoring one database.

Answer (score 0):

Use "multi-source replication", which is available on your servers (as of 10.0.1).  See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/multi-source-replication/ for details.

It would go something like this:

1. Set up the replication from A1 to B1, but not "turn it on".
2. Take some form of dump (mysqldump, xtrabackup, etc) of the databases of A1 you want to copy.  Be sure to grab the position in the binlog.
3. Load them on B1.
4. Turn on replication so that it will catchup.
5. Retire A1/2/3.

(As Rolando say, try it out before doing it in Production.)

Comment: Thx, do know how to restoring one database by the xtrabackup ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a good summary to give you here.